# Bootstrap Vue table - select rows programmatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, bootstrap-4

**VueJS: 2.6.6**

**Bootstrap Vue: 2.0.0-rc.13**

Is it possible to preselect some rows from the start based on a parameter(**'_selectedRow'** for example like **'_rowVariant'**) or to select them programmatically?

The selected rows array is empty after refresh() method so I need a way to select the rows.

Comment: Hi @Dorin, you're probably looking for this [issue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/2687), which has solved my problem as well.